# Pickle serialization order mystery

Tags: python, dictionary, serialization, pickle, stream-framework

**Update 6/8/17**

Though 3 years passed, my [PR](https://github.com/tschellenbach/Stream-Framework/pull/53) is still pending as a temporary solution by enforcing the output order. Stream-Framework might reconsider its design on using content as key for notifications. GitHub [Issue #153](https://github.com/tschellenbach/Stream-Framework/issues/153) references this.

**Question**

See following sample:

```
import pickle
x = {'order_number': 'X', 'deal_url': 'J'}

pickle.dumps(x)
pickle.dumps(pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(x)))
pickle.dumps(pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(x)))))
```

Results:

```
(dp0\nS'deal_url'\np1\nS'J'\np2\nsS'order_number'\np3\nS'X'\np4\ns.
(dp0\nS'order_number'\np1\nS'X'\np2\nsS'deal_url'\np3\nS'J'\np4\ns.
(dp0\nS'deal_url'\np1\nS'J'\np2\nsS'order_number'\np3\nS'X'\np4\ns.
```

Clearly, serialized output changes for every dump. When I remove a character from any of keys, this doesn't happen. I discovered this as [Stream-Framework](https://github.com/tschellenbach/Stream-Framework) use pickled output as key for storage of notifications on its k/v store. I will pull request if we get a better understanding what is going on here. I have found two solutions to prevent it:

A - Convert to dictionary after sorting (yes, somehow provides the intended side effect)

```
import operator
sorted_x = dict(sorted(x.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)))
```

B - Remove underscores (but not sure if this always works)

So what causes the mystery under dictionary sorting for pickle?

Proof that calling sort over dict provides dump to produce same result:

```
import operator
x = dict(sorted(x.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)))

pickle.dumps(x)
"(dp0\nS'order_number'\np1\nS'X'\np2\nsS'deal_url'\np3\nS'J'\np4\ns."

x = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(x))
x = dict(sorted(x.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)))

pickle.dumps(x)
"(dp0\nS'order_number'\np1\nS'X'\np2\nsS'deal_url'\np3\nS'J'\np4\ns."
```

Comment: `dict` does not keep the keys' order. You should consider using `OrderedDict` from `collections`.

Comment: There is no mystery. Dictionaries are unordered.

Comment: In definition I agree, but if I apply solution A after each load, dump produces the same result magically. So pickle is somehow affected by the memory order or something.

Comment: So you'd rather come up with a way to accidentally order the dict the way you want instead of switching to an order-preserving data structure?

Comment: Have you noticed that calling `dict(sorted(x.iteritems()))` with key being what ever you choose will always result in *one* possible order of the dictionary? The key is irrelevant because the operation makes no sense. There's no difference. You are going to have a **bad time** if you put any trust in this in any real environment. Your test dataset also contains a dictionary with two keys. Try one with a few thousand and see how that works out.

Comment: Guys, I think that is because there is a difference on dict returned by load which affects the next dump (pickle may hooking something on the instance?). Whatever it changes in interpreter, pickle gets affected for next time. Actually, sorted() helped making a fresh copy that is why I believe it resulted expected correct output. I agree, dump/loads several times is still an edge and wrong use case of pickle anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dictionaries are unsorted data structures. This means that the order is arbitrary and pickle will store them as they are. You can use the [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) if you want to use a sorted dictionary.

Any order you think you see when you're playing around in the interpreter is just the interpreter playing nice with you.

From the documentation of [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

> It is best to think of a dictionary as an unordered set of key: value pairs, with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one dictionary)

Remember that the functions `dict.keys()`, `dict.values()` and `dict.items()` also return their respective values in arbitrary order.

Comment: You realize that the moment you call `pickle.loads(dictionary_pickle)` you construct a dictionary which has *arbitrary* order, regardless of the order of how pickle stored that dictionary?

Comment: Also the solution A you offer creates a dictionary after sorting the result of `iteritems()`, effectively losing order.

Comment: And it still solves the problem :) I agree pickle has rights to choose its own presentation, but I have forced it to be same, just added the proof to question.

Comment: The order of a given `dict` is likely to be the same from run to run *given the input method is the same and the same version of Python is being used*.  Your data simply reinforces this.