# Hash sum of an object in python

Tags: python, hash

In my script I work with large and complex object (a multi-dimentional list that contains strings, dictionaries, and class objects of custom types). I need to copy, pickle (cache) and unpickle it, as well as send between child processes through `MPI` interface. At some points I get suspicious that the data transfer is error-free, i.e. if in the end I have the same object.

Therefore, I want to calculate its hash sum or some other type of fingerprint. I know that there is, for example, `hashlib` library; however, it is limited in terms of object type:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> a = "123"
>>> hashlib.sha224(a.encode()).hexdigest()
'78d8045d684abd2eece923758f3cd781489df3a48e1278982466017f'
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> hashlib.sha224(a).hexdigest()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object supporting the buffer API required
```

Thus, the question: is there some analog of this function that works with objects of any type?

Comment: You can hash the string that you're transferring

Comment: Can you not stringify your objects and compute the hash on them? For e.g `>>> a=[1,2,3] 
>>> hashlib.sha224(str(a)).hexdigest()
'b22ce0e22158ce757c93660ca016d2a417eb4f2c9c2c40cb7809ae1a'`

Comment: You can implement your own `__hash__` for your object.

Comment: @linuxfan I suspect that would be sensitive to order for e.g. dictionaries

Comment: @jonrsharpe Good point - thanks for the edification.

Comment: If you have control over the objects, you might be able to use `collections.OrderedDict` to work around the ordering issue discussed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pickle.dumps(...)
```

returns a string, which is a hashable object. You can do it as follows

```
import pickle
a=[1,2,3,4]
h=pickle.dumps(a)
print hash(h)

# or like this

from hashlib import sha512
print sha512(h).hexdigest()

c=pickle.loads(h)
assert c==a
```

Comment: This won't give consistent results for dictionaries, sets, etc. - see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/23069908/3001761

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to recursively convert all elements of the structure into hashable counterparts, i.e. lists into tuples, dicts and objects into frozensets, and then simply apply `hash()` to the whole thing.  An illustration:

```
def to_hashable(s):
    if isinstance(s, dict):
        return frozenset((x, to_hashable(y)) for x, y in s.items())
    if isinstance(s, list):
        return tuple(to_hashable(x) for x in s)
    if isinstance(s, set):
        return frozenset(s)
    if isinstance(s, MyObject):
        d = {'__class__': s.__class__.__name__}
        d.update(s.__dict__)
        return to_hashable(d)
    return s

class MyObject:
    pass

class X(MyObject):
    def __init__(self, zzz):
        self.zzz = zzz

my_list = [
    1,
    {'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6]},
    {1,2,3,4,5},
    X({1:2,3:4}),
    X({5:6,7:8})
]

print hash(to_hashable(my_list))

my_list2 = [
    1,
    {'b': [4,5,6], 'a': [1,2,3]},
    {5,4,3,2,1},
    X({3:4,1:2}),
    X({7:8,5:6})
]

print hash(to_hashable(my_list2)) # the same as above
```